# How to call an URL based on search field input in ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a search form on my index page.

```
<form  method="post" action="search.php?go"  id="searchform"> 
          <input  type="text" name="name"> 
          <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"> 
        </form>
```

This is part of the code on the search.php

```
var url = "https://externalwebsite.com/search?term=" + searchterms + "&variable2=something";
    $.getJSON(url,function(data) {

        var somevariable = Object.keys(data).length;

           var div_data = '';
            $.each(data, function(i,data) {
    if ($("#some_div").html() == '');
......
```

I want to call an external search engine that gives back data in json.

How do I get the search terms into the ajax variable "searchterms" so I can add the search terms to the URL of an external search engine?
I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

You can't necessarily read from another website, this is to prevent XSS (Cross Site Scripting) attacks.

If you were able to read from other websites, you could potentially steal information from users. The only way to make requests to another website is through "JSONP".

[JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) bypasses the security requirements by acting as an external script. Instead of loading raw JSON data `{"type":"JSON"}`, it calls a function using the raw data. `jsonpFunction({"type":"JSONP"});`

You have to provide the callback function in order to handle it.

Comment: Thanks, Until now I could parse the info without problems by using fixed data. Now I try to do the same based on dynamic data.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `input` field called `name` is the field you want to pull terms from, give it an ID:

```
<input  type="text" name="name" id="searchbox">
```

Then get the value using jQuery:

```
var searchterms = $('#searchbox').val();
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't get it to work yet, but it seems right. I will check the answer as soon as it works.

Comment: The problem is, I am a beginner and I don't really get ajax yet. I had a code that parsed json data which I got from my own database and which worked fine. Now I try to reuse that code for the external json data, but nothing shows yet.

I don't even know, if the external data is loaded yet.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code,

Replace **url** with your own

```js
var searchterms = '';

function getTerm(term) {
  console.log(term);
  $('.term').text(term);
}


$("#submit").on("click", function() {
  searchterms = $("#searchbox").val();
  console.log(searchterms);
  var url = "https://externalwebsite.com/search?term=" + searchterms + "&variable2=something";
  console.log(url);
  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="name" id="searchbox" onkeydown="getTerm(this.value);">

<input type="button" id="submit" value="search">

<p class='term'></p>
```

Comment: Thanks, I give up. I am too stupid for ajax. I think I have found a way to do it in php only.